Find last cell with data for specific "search key" in google sheets
I am new to spreadsheets!
I have created a google form to track a service technician's daily time record. The technician might visit multiple sites in a day. As Forms does not allow looping questions, I have had to create a number of duplicate sections.
The Google Sheet attached to the form is here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zzivoIt2gfrb21mRpE2sbiZA37hc-sLUYgDT74qcf6Q/edit?usp=sharing
I am wondering if anyone can explain to me how to build a formula that will give me the "Daily Finish" time ("Processed Data" Sheet, Column "AS") from the last recorded "FINISH" time in the row?
I have tried using XLOOKUP but that only gives me the data from either the first or last "Finish" column, not the last "Finish" column with data, ignoring blank cells


You may try:
=byrow(A2:AP,lambda(Σ,choosecols(ifna(filter(Σ,A1:AP1="Finish",Σ<>"")),-1)))


logic:

range(lets say A2:P2 row) is designated as Σ, you can also change Σ to something of your choice
filter(Σ,A1:AP1="Finish",Σ<>"") Here I am filtering the specific row where the header (in A1:P1) is Finish & at the same time I am also disregarding the cells with blanks in the row
choosecols(.....,-1) In the last step I am picking the last non-blank value from the filter output obtained in step 2


Thank you so much! Could you please explain the lambda part a little further? How did you type the function symbol? I like to understand how a solution works so I am better equipped to figure things out for myself in the future.

Added a bit of formula backend explanation to the answer
